# Bubble sort algorithm in an array of strings runs with no erros, but does nothing

Tags: c, bubble-sort, c-strings

It's supposed to sort the 30 names in `nombres` in alphabetical order, the function `burbuja()` executes, but after it finishes all the names are still unsorted

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define max 30

int mostrar(char nombres[max][80])
{
    int i;
    printf("\nLa pila ahora tiene los siguentes elementos\n");
    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
        printf("%s\n",nombres[i]);
}

void burbuja(char nombres[max][80]) //part that does not work
{
    int i, j;
    char aux[80];
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < max - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if(nombres[j - 1] > nombres[j])
            {
                strcpy(aux, nombres[j - 1]);
                strcpy(nombres[j - 1], nombres[j]);
                strcpy(nombres[j], aux);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char nombres[30][80] = {
        "Javier", "Paola", "Paco", "Pedro", "Jorge", "Luis", "Champ",
        "Alma", "Alicia", "Stephanie", "Mark", "Daniel", "Hank", "Malcom",
        "Jaime", "Luisa", "Lila", "Beatriz", "Teresa", "Maria", "Michel", 
        "Karina", "Karen", "Carmen", "Juan", "Daniela", "Ana", "Gavin",
        "Rosa", "Francisco"
    };

    mostrar(nombres);
    burbuja(nombres);
    mostrar(nombres);
}
```

it show correctly the names unsorted, bubble function does the thing, then it show all the same names still unsorted

...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console

Comment: `nombres[j-1] > nombres[j]`: don't you want to use `strncmp` and friends? You're now comparing pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `nombres[j - 1] > nombres[j]`, both `nombres[j-1]` and `nombres[j]` are character arrays. And an array name by itself decays into a pointer to the first element of that array.

So by `nombres[j - 1] > nombres[j]`, you are merely comparing the *pointers to the* first element of the two arrays.

You need a function like [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp).

And `for (j = i + 1; j < max - i - 1; j++)` won't cover the whole array properly.

Try something like

```
for (i=0; i<max; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<max-1-i; j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(nombres[j], nombres[j+1])>0)
        {
            strcpy(aux, nombres[j]);
            strcpy(nombres[j], nombres[j+1]);
            strcpy(nombres[j+1], aux);
        }
    }
}
```

`strcmp()` returns a value greater than zero if the first string comes after the second in lexicographical order.

Edit:

As [David C. Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) pointed out, you could make the return type of the `mostrar()` function to `void` as you are not returning any value.

Comment: You may want to mention `int mostrar (..)` should be `void mostrar (..)` as no value is returned.

Comment: First element of what? You're comparing the **pointers to the first elements** of each (sub)array.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is not bubble sort but rather insertion sort.

Bubble sort keeps track of whether a swap occurred, and if so, it then repeats the process of comparing neighboring elements until the array is sorted.

Insertion sort compares the first ith element with the next jth where j > i until the end of the array, if the ith element is greater than jth element then a swap occurs.

Also the invariant for your second `for` loop inside `barbuja()` is wrong, rather it should be `j < max`, and as pointed out by user 9769953 you should use a function that does string comparison such as `strcmp()` or `strncmp()`

Comment: In fact it is better if it is insertion sort. Everytime someone codes a bubble sort, the FSM kills a kitten.